Bluetooth mouse doesn't recoonect after some time on Ubuntu 24.04
My bluetooth mice (I've tried two a Logi MX Anywhere 3S and an MX 650) work when I set up the connection in settings but after some time (like leaving the laptop on but not logged in) will stop responding until I forget the device and reconnect it.
I tried running systemctl status bluetooth.service and get:
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-13 12:36:16 AEST; 1 week 2 days ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1174 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18316)
     Memory: 4.5M (peak: 5.0M swap: 320.0K swap peak: 328.0K)
        CPU: 1min 37.801s
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1174 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Jul 21 14:22:20 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.4815 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Jul 21 18:44:59 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
Jul 21 18:45:15 ivan bluetoothd[1174]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)

I'm not sure if the last two lines is something to worry but but have seen suggestion to turn AutoEnable = true in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf which it is
also when I ran sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth when my mouse wasn't connecting I saw nothing but after remove/reconnect I see
[802441.775601] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[802442.976804] hid-generic 0005:046D:B037.0009: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Mouse [MX Anywhere 3S] on 4c:82:a9:82:ed:c2

Any suggestions on what I can do to get my mouse to automatically reconnect (Note presently I don't have any other bluetooth devices attached so I'm not 100% sure if it's mouse specific or generally bluethooth)

All I can see from what you have posted is that the Bluetooth service is running and seems to have been running for a few days. It would appear that the mice are timing out. Have you investigated on the Logitech site info on the mice?

The MX Anywhere 3S is several years old and worked with 4+ versions of Ubuntu I don't think its the mouse.
